# How to remote into a computer with no password

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a couple of computers with Remote Desktop enabled (the more secure choice), and an IT computer running Windows 7 Pro.  I would like to be able to use Remote Desktop Connection from the IT computer to the other computers without sacrificing security or speed.  What I had in mind was something that used IP or user-name.  There is no central server, just LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a firewall rule that restricts access to the RDP ports on those machines to only accept remote connections from a specific IP or range of IPs. You can go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771905.aspx) for some more details on how to do this on Windows 7 firewall.

BTW. The default RDP port is 3389 and there should already be a rule accepting incoming connections from any source. You just have to modify it to accept connections from a specific IP.